# Elastic Search with SpringBoot not working

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm a completely new to elasticsearch, I would like to connect my webapplication developped using Springboot (1.3.1.RELEASE) to a remote elastic search instance installed in a unix VM, so I added the following to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And this is the configuration in my application.yml

```
 spring:
   data:
     elasticsearch:
       host: 192.168.56.101
       port: 9300
       cluster-nodes: 192.168.56.101:9300
```

but I'm getting the following exception:

```
2015-12-20 23:26:58.621  INFO 8580 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1]    o.s.d.e.c.TransportClientFactoryBean     : adding transport node :   192.168.56.101:9300
2015-12-20 23:26:58.710  WARN 8580 --- [ I/O worker #1}]    org.elasticsearch.transport.netty        : [Coldfire] Message not fully read (response) for [0] handler   future(org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SimpleNodeSampler$1@54acdf57), error [true], resetting
2015-12-20 23:26:58.717  INFO 8580 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] org.elasticsearch.client.transport       : [Coldfire] failed to get node info for [#transport#-1][fgonzalez-HP][inet[/192.168.56.101:9300]], disconnecting...

org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: Failed to deserialize exception response from stream
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportSerializationException: Failed to deserialize exception response from stream
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:176) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:128) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: Unsupported version: 1
```

Does someone know the reason of this exception?

Looks like an incompatibility with the version installed of ElasticSearch (2.1.1).

Does it mean that I cannot use the latest version of Springboot with the latest version of elastic search? Should I then downgrade my version of elastic search or someone knows any other fix?

In case it helps, this is the document I created:

```
@Document(indexName = "lng_index",type = "")
public class LanguageDoc {

@Id
private String id;

private String text;

public LanguageDoc() {
}

public LanguageDoc(String id, String text) {
    this.id = id;
    this.text = text;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
}
```

My Spring Data repo:

```
@Repository
public interface LanguageRepository extends   ElasticsearchRepository<LanguageDoc,String> {
}
```

And the elasticsearch.yml :

```
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
# bootstrap.mlockall: true
#
# Make sure that the `ES_HEAP_SIZE` environment variable is set to about   half the memory
# available on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to   use this limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -------------------------------  ----
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
#   network.host: 192.168.0.1
network.host: 0.0.0.0
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
# http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules- network.html>
```

Thank you in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the record, in case someone else faces the same issue, I have fixed it by downgrading the version of ElasticSearch to 1.5.2 (the same as the in memory instance of elasticSearch that is coming with Sprinboot)

Comment: I lost hours looking for the cause. Finally it was a version mismatch as you pointed out. I find it a bit disappointing that this is not stated in any of the (to my taste) poor documentation out there.Thanks for sharing the solution.

Comment: @fgonzalez: Its not logical to include and older version of Elasticsearch dependency instead of using the latest release. Simlarly, I am trying to use spring-data-elasticsearch 2.0.1 RELEASE and its fetch elasticsearch.1.5.2.RELEASE jar. This would keep spring-data from using any of the new feature available in latest ES release.

Comment: If you get working that version of Springboot with the latest version of ES let me know. At that time I couldn't, so that was the easiest way to workaround the issue. Anyway for what I need from ES with the 1.5.2 is enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use JEST client.

just add dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.searchbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>jest</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

and configure using

```
spring.elasticsearch.jest.uris=http://192.168.99.100:9200
spring.elasticsearch.jest.read-timeout=5000
```

[Link to documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-nosql.html#boot-features-connecting-to-elasticsearch-jest)